# Duplicate slugs in categories

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, let me explain the problem.

The following happens when I make categories with similar names:

- https://www.example.com/cars/ford/parts
- https://www.example.com/cars/toyota/parts1

Why is this the case? The parents are different so why would WordPress at a 1 to the second parts category?

**Is there a workaround for this?**
I saw numerous people with the same issue. Would be nice if there was a way for them to have the same slugs when the parent's slug is different.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress won't allow you to have duplicate term slugs in the same taxonomy, they need to be unique in the database. However, we can extend WordPress core to make the url structure work while maintaining the unique term slugs.

Using your example: `cars/ford/parts` and `cars/toyota/parts` urls where `ford_parts` and `toyota_parts` are the unique child terms in the `cars` taxonomy and their parent term slugs are `ford` and `toyota`, respectively.

First, the rewrite rule:

```php
/**
 * Add custom rewrite rules for parent/child term urls.
 *
 * Adds a rewrite rule that will match terms 
 * that have their slug prefixed with the parent term
 * slug, separated by an underscore, but their url
 * is just the child term slug.
 */
function prefix_custom_hierarchical_taxonomy_rewrite_rules() {

    $tax_object = get_taxonomy( 'cars' );

    if ( $tax_object ) {
        $tax_slug = $tax_object->rewrite['slug'];
        add_rewrite_rule(
            $tax_object->rewrite['slug'] . '/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?',
            'index.php?' . $tax_object->query_var . '=$matches[1]_$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'prefix_custom_hierarchical_taxonomy_rewrite_rules', 100 );
```

Then filter the `term_link` such that you remove the "parent_" part of the slug in the child term's link:

```php
/**
 * Filter the term link to handle hierarchical taxonomy permalinks.
 *
 * This will filter the term link to remove the parent term slug
 * from the child term url, so that the url is just the child term slug,
 * where the child term name is "parent_child" and the parent term name is "parent".
 *
 * @param string $link The term link
 * @param WP_Term $term The term object
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy name
 * @return string
 */
function prefix_custom_term_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy ) {

    if ( $taxonomy !== 'cars' ) {
        return $link;
    }

    // Get the parent term
    $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );

    if ( $parent_term && ! is_wp_error( $parent_term ) ) {
        // Remove the "parent_" prefix from the child term slug
        // to generate a url that looks like /parent/child/
        $link = str_replace( '/' . $term->slug, '/' . str_replace ( $parent_term->slug . '_', '', $term->slug ), $link );
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'prefix_custom_term_link', 10, 3 );
```

You may also want to filter the `parse_query` to check for any child terms that don't follow this structure. This avoids having to set *all* your child category slugs to the `parent_child` pattern, you can just apply it to those that have a "duplicated" url slug.

**Note:** this next example is looking for the `category_name` query variable, which is used by the `category` taxonomy. For your custom taxonomy that will likely be different - see [register_taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)

```php
/**
 * Parse the query to handle hierarchical taxonomy permalinks.
 *
 * This filter the query to check for terms that are child terms
 * yet do not have the parent term in the slug, thus the parent/child
 * structure should literally look for a "child" slug, not "parent_child"
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query The WP_Query instance (passed by reference)
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_custom_parse_query($query) {
    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['category_name'] ) ) {
        $slug = $query->query_vars['category_name'];
        if ( strpos( $slug, '_' ) !== false ) {
            list( $parent, $child ) = explode( '_', $slug, 2 );
            if ( ! term_exists( $slug, 'category' ) && term_exists( $child, 'category' ) ) {
                $query->query_vars['category_name'] = $child;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'prefix_custom_parse_query' );
```

I've put this into a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/joshuadavidnelson/282614233c25071669f2502d77a7a8f9) but using the `category` taxonomy instead of a custom `cars` taxonomy.

Notes:

- This only works with hierarchical taxonomies
- Update the `prefix_` naming to something unique to your theme or plugin.
- This example uses a custom term slug for your child terms that follows a pattern like `{parent-slug}_{child-slug}`. You could change that to another separating character, but be careful to use a dash `-` as that is the default used by core when names are generated (spaces turn to dashes).
- This requires [the "pretty" permalinks](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/#pretty-permalinks) where `/%postname%/` is set in the Settings > Permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never quite suffered enough to figure out why it happens, but I can confirm that it happens. I've only had to deal with a cleanup, but nobody wanted to add additional categories, so my lazyness stopped me after a simple fix.

What I've done was directly working on WP's tables (wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy), setting the correct term_id on the wp_term_taxonomy-item that was created with the second (duplicate) term, thus getting a different slug. This was a straight forward, pretty harmless action, because it doesn't change the term_taxonomy_id and therefore didn't concern wp_term_relationships at all.

As usual when manipulating the data directly, do it on a dev installation first.

Answer (score -1):

I have use plugin where I need permalinks related customisation.Its work like charm.I hop this will helpful.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/